Implement antiforgery in ASP.NET 8 Core Web API to prevent from CSRF attack
I have created an ASP.NET 8 Core Web API and frontend is hosted on some other domain. I want to prevent CSRF attacks that is why I want to use antiforgery in my API. I am calling the API using AJAX and I am already using Jwt tokens - I guess that will not make any affect.
This is my setup - Program.cs:
builder.Services.AddAntiforgery(options =>
{
    options.HeaderName = "X-CSRF-TOKEN";
});

Controller method:
[Authorize]
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class AdminController : HelperController
{
    private readonly ErrorResponseService _errorResponseService;
    private readonly IAntiforgery _antiforgery;

    public AdminController(TruCastContext dbContext, IWebHostEnvironment hostEnvironment, TokenBlacklistService tokenBlacklistService, IConfiguration configuration, EmailService emailService, ErrorResponseService errorResponseService, IAntiforgery antiforgery, ILogger<AdminController> logger)
    {
        _dbContext = dbContext;
        _errorResponseService = errorResponseService;
        _antiforgery = antiforgery;
    }

    // POST: Get User and Channel Counts
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("GetUserAndChannelCounts")]
    public IActionResult GetUserAndChannelCounts()
    {
        try
        {
            var token = _antiforgery.GetTokens(HttpContext).RequestToken;

            var tokenFromHeader = Request.Headers["X-CSRF-TOKEN"].ToString();

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(tokenFromHeader))
            {
                return StatusCode(400, new { Message = "No anti-forgery token found in request header" });
            }
 
            // Perform token validation
            if (!_antiforgery.IsRequestValidAsync(HttpContext).Result)
            {
                return StatusCode(400, new { Message = "Invalid anti-forgery token" });
            }

            var counts = new Count
                {
                    UserTotalCount = _dbContext.UserDetails.Count(),
                    UserActiveCount = _dbContext.UserDetails.Count(u => u.IsActive),
                    UserInactiveCount = _dbContext.UserDetails.Count(u => !u.IsActive),
                    ChannelTotalCount = _dbContext.ChannelDetails.Count(),
                    ChannelActiveCount = _dbContext.ChannelDetails.Count(c => c.IsActive),
                    ChannelInactiveCount = _dbContext.ChannelDetails.Count(c => !c.IsActive)
                };

            // success response
            var successResponse = new
                {
                    Status = 200,
                    Message = "Count fetched successfully",
                    Details = counts
                };

            return Ok(successResponse);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            var errorResponse = _errorResponseService.CreateErrorResponse(500, "Internal Server Error: " + ex.Message);
            return StatusCode(500, errorResponse);
        }
    }
}

Dashboard.cshtml:
<form id="dashboardform" asp-antiforgery="true">
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()  <!-- this generates the anti-forgery token -->
</form>

Dashboard.js:
$(document).ready(function () {
    let connection = getAPIConnection();
    let jwtToken = localStorage.getItem("jwtToken");
    GetCount();
    function GetCount() {
        isLoading = true;
        var url = connection + "api/Admin/Count";

        // Get the Anti-Forgery token from the hidden input field
        var antiForgeryToken = $('input[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val();
            console.log("Anti-Forgery Token: ", antiForgeryToken);  // Check if the token is populated
        
        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + jwtToken,
                'X-CSRF-TOKEN': antiForgeryToken // Include Anti-Forgery token
            },
             
            success: function (response) {
                if (response.Status === 200) {
                    console.log("Forgery Token: ", antiForgeryToken)
                    // Access the counts directly from the Details object
                    $('#tcCount').text(response.Details.ChannelTotalCount);
                } else if (response.Status === 404) {
                    console.error("Counts not found");
                } else {
                    console.error("Failed to retrieve channel details");
                }
            }
,
            error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                console.error("Error occurred: ", error);
            }
        });
    }
});

I added antiforgery in program.cs file and added manual antiforgery in my controller method to validate which is being sent through frontend header in correct format, but I get this error all the time:

Invalid Anti-Forgery Token

I am expecting that API should return the data instead of an error

Your implementation isn't correct.  If site A generates a CSRF token, that token is used when posting back to a page on site A.  That token will not work on site B, but this is what you're trying to do.
If you have a JWT token that authenticates A against B, you don't need CSRF.

Okay! I understand. But as per the requirement I have to use AntiForgery. So, what would be the correct method to use it here.

Though CORS is not a security feature, you could implement it in your API to restrict cross domain requests(which are restricted by default). Or, you could write services in your front-end web application that would validate anti forgery token and fetch the data from your API through an httpclient.

You will use Antiforgery in situations where a page on A posts back to A.  It cannot be done from A to B.  Maybe to achieve the requirement, you shouldn't be making any cross site requests.  In that case, A would post to A, which would call B from within the front-end server side code, and then return results to the browser.  But as is, your approach won't support CSRF.
